# PHP / MySQL special characters issue Â

Tags: php, special-characters, html-entities

I am getting a very strange problem... I am creating a website and storing data in `mysql` and data is phrased from different types of sources in the database. But the text and html I am storing is not clean. It's also saved some special characters and and extra space. Now how can I clean this data with php when I render it as html. I used `trim()` and `html_entity_decode()`.

These functions removed some white spaces but I still can't clean these **Â** characters.

Here is screenshot from my phpmyadmin : http://postimg.org/image/ze8umokej/

And here is a screenshot of my page source : http://postimg.org/image/rdz5bxsuj/

Comment: Prepare regular expression which matches your special character and the  use preg_replace function to replace those character with blank.

Comment: can you please show me a example there is only one special character "Â" which i want to clean..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prepared a regular expression and replaced it with balnk.

```
$str = "Â some text";

echo $str = preg_replace('/[^\x00-\x7F]/',"",$str);
```

Comment: @SunilMeena if you like the answer you can upvote and mark it accepted. So it will be useful to other and build some confidence..